# vim backspace not working after stty erase ^?

Tags: vim

Since backspace in vim was giving me `^?` instead of working as a backspace, I put the following in `.cshrc` to make it work:

```
stty erase ^?
```

Now the problem is that when I open a gnome-terminal from my linux machine, the backspace still does not work in vim. However if I run tcsh on my shell, and reopen vim, backspace does work. If I open a gnome-terminal tab in the already open terminal, or open a new terminal window from the already open terminal on which tcsh was run, I don't see the issue. Could anyone tell me what might be going on?

Comment: Is your `$TERM` set correctly? Are you overriding it anywhere?

Comment: $TERM is set correctly. Its value is xterm. I checked that it has same value  before and after running tcsh on a fresh terminal

Comment: Have you set "set backspace=eol,start,indent" in your vimrc?

Comment: Yes, I have set backspace=eol,start,indent already